# The icon of my iOS application is not displayed in iPads (but fine with simulators) [Swift, iOS, Xcode]

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I am creating an iOS application for iPads with Swift 5, Xcode 13.1.
Last time I changed my icons by replacing images in `Assets.xcassets`. However, suddenly the app icon became not properly displayed on my iPad for some reason. Now the app icon is just a grid.

There are two weird things happening:

1. The icons are actually properly displayed when testing with simulators.
2. Then I reversed all of the modifications using `GitHub`, but the app still does not show its icon, even with using all files that used to show the icon properly.

I have tried:

1. rebooting my `MacBook Pro` and `iPads` (mini 6th & pro 11 inch.)
2. `clean build`,
3. made sure `App Icons Source` was appropriately selected
4. recreate `new iOS app icon` in Assets with `Xcode`
5. tested with other icon files that are confirmed to be working with other apps
6. re-install `Xcode`
7. Tried with my iPhone

However, none of the above solved the problem. I would appreciate it very much if I could know what is happening and how I can show the app icon properly.

## Update!

I updated iPads and iPhones to iOS 15.1, and the problem was solved... temporally. When changing the icon files, I realized that the icons were not displayed properly with iPads but not with iPhones and. All of the simulators stopped displaying the icons properly. Further playing with `Xcode`, I realized that `include all app icon assets` was ticked, so I changed it to ticked and vise versa. This appeared to cause the problem..., But honestly could not replicate the problem that clearly!

Currently, the changing icons are appropriately reflected in my `iPad Pro 6th gen`, but not in my `iPhones`. `Simulators` are not showing icons appropriately either!

I would really appreciate it if somebody could explain what is happing to me.

Comment: Have you deleted the app from your iPad before re-installing it?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @JoakimDanielson. Yes, I deleted the app before re-installing it. However, this did not help..

Comment: how are you making the icons - are they all included in the assets? Does changing the source image for the icons themselves have an impact?

Comment: Usually, I use mac's `Preview` to resize `jpeg` images to create icons. This time, I tried to use `https://appiconmaker.co/` to create resized icons automatically. This created differently sized `png` images.  It seems like sometimes changing source images made difference (fail/success of change), other times not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated iPads and iPhones to iOS 15.1, and the problem solved completely!! Now all icons are displayed properly.

### Update 1

The above solve the problem... temporally. Then, further playing with `Xcode`, I realized that `include all app icon assets` was ticked and this was causing all of the icon problems.

Once I ticked off `include all app icon assets`, I was actually able to change the image files from `Assets` and reflect it on my app.

### Update 2

When I reopened `Xcode` again today, for some reason, all simulators displayed icons properly. iPhones and iPads are working fine as well. `include all app icon assets` does not SEEM to have influence now...?

I honestly have no idea.. But, I could say if somebody is struggling with the same icon issue, `updating everything` might change the situation...